# FakeItEasy: Fake a call to a generic method without specifying the type

Tags: c#, generics, fakeiteasy

I have a type that relies on an external component that executes queries through a generic method.  Here's a simplified version of what's in play:

```
public class UnitUnderTest
{
    private IQueryEngine _engine;

    public UnitUnderTest(IQueryEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }

    public OutputType DoSomething() 
    {
         _engine.Query<ExternalType>(...);
         _engine.Query<InternalType>(...);
    }
}

public interface IQueryEngine
{
    IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string conditions);
}
```

The `DoSomething` method I'm trying to test calls `IQueryEngine` twice.

The first time it calls it with a type I can access from my test so I have no problem using `A.CallTo` to mock it.

But then it calls a second time with a type argument that I can't access (it's an `internal` type).

Right now my test is bombing because `DoSomething` is not expecting back a null from the call to `_engine.Query`, but I cannot construct the proper type of object to return.

How can I mock out this call?

Comment: why don't you add the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute?

Comment: Ideally I would have rather not done it this way, but since I did have control over the library where `InternalType` is defined, this is the solution I went with.  If you turn this into an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use of the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. Just add an instance to your assembly with the internal type with your test assembly as the value.